# Why is IoTHubMessages an array in Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

I have messages from Azure IoT hub and I context.log the bindings of IoTHubMessages. It shows object.

[image]

The code in the image above is working.As you can see the console when the function is triggered, It log the IoTHubMessages as an object. But the code still works when I loop them.
How is that happening?

Comment: How many times does the forEach() loop ?

Comment: @HuryShen 1 , and 0 with index

Comment: So I think it just think of the one message(object) as an array, the array just contains one item. If we set the value of property `cardinality` in "function.json" to `many`, it will think of the `IoTHubMessages` as array(even if it has only one item). If you set the `cardinality` to `one`, it will show error message when execute the "forEach()" line because it can just accept one message and can't do forEach().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on Hury Shen's comment: When you create a new Azure Functions App in JavaScript (through VSCode), the function.json will automatically have cardinality set to many. This will allow messages to be batched, which is why your input parameter is an array. If you don't get a lot of messages, you will see arrays with only 1 value being passed into your Function.

If you change many to one:

```
"cardinality": "one",
```

Then messages will never be batched and your input parameter will be a single message, even when there are a lot of messages coming in. There is a [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-iot-trigger?tabs=javascript#configuration) that mentions this configuration.

Comment: I context.log typeof  ```IoTHubMessages``` It showed object

Comment: That's because the type of an array is actually an object in JavaScript. To check if a variable is an array you can use Array.isArray(IoTHubMessages). This will return true when cardinality is set to many, and false when it is set to one.